# Why doesn't tcp_transmit_skb delete the skbuff in the write queue whereas udp_send_skb does

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming, udp

I'm trying to implement a new protocol on top of UDP in the linux kernel. I need to implement flow control for this protocol but when I use the function `udp_send_skb()`, the transmitted skbuff gets removed from the write queue.

How does TCP manage to send an skbuff without removing it from the queue? I think the relevant tcp function is `tcp_transmit_skb()`.

Once I understand this behaviour in TCP, I can do that in UDP. Or maybe someone can point out what to change in `udp_send_skb` (or in the functions called by it) to ensure that the skbuff is not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I'll use `skb_clone()` and send out the clone instead of the original skb. I found this while going through the `tcp_transmit_skb` function